# How can you call a local web page with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, local

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I can't seem to find an answer.  I'm working on PHP development, creating a basic login connected with mySQL database. Once the name/password is verified correct, I would like to show a welcome screen.  My issue is that during development, I can't use a local directory like:

**`header("location:script/login_success.php");`**

From what I've read, **header()** is looking for an `http:// URL`.  Is there any way to be able to test locally?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried `header("location:http://localhost/script/login_success.php");`?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass relative url to `header` there is no problem.

```
header("Location: /route/here.php");
```

is perfectly legit. Although the RFC dictates absolute URLs including the schema must be provided. Some web clients accepts the relative URL. [Dagon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557846/dagon) pointed the RFC Matter.

> 14.30 Location
>
> The Location response-header field is used to redirect the recipient
>   to a location other than the Request-URI for completion of the request
>   or identification of a new resource. For 201 (Created) responses, the
>   Location is that of the new resource which was created by the request.
>   For 3xx responses, the location SHOULD indicate the server's preferred
>   URI for automatic redirection to the resource. The field value
>   consists of a single absolute URI.

```
Location       = "Location" ":" absoluteURI An example is:
Location: http://www.w3.org/pub/WWW/People.html
```

> ```
>   Note: The Content-Location header field (section 14.14) differs
>   from Location in that the Content-Location identifies the original
>   location of the entity enclosed in the request. It is therefore
>   possible for a response to contain header fields for both Location
>   and Content-Location. Also see section 13.10 for cache
>   requirements of some methods.
> ```

Comment: no its not legit, it should use the full URI not a relative one.

Comment: wrong, you do. From the manual "HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs. You can usually use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and dirname() to make an absolute URI from a relative one yourself: "

Comment: you quote from the manual that "*The field value consists of a single absolute URI.*" yet keep insisting on a relative one -odd

Comment: i like to let people know all the options :). personally i have used relative URLs all the time, yet to have a problem. But i appreciate you pointing out the RFC. Let me add credit to you :)

Answer (score 0):

`Header` has to be the first function call in page (you can access other functions but no output ones not even space or enter).. above everything(echo and html)... it should work everywhere...

When you `echo` the response is written partially and header is `200 ok`... so... just write `header` first and then `exit();`

`header('Location: url')` ... I don't think url has to be relative... read on php.net

Comment: no it doesn't there can be many other functions before header() just no output

Comment: Yes... to not write the header... like `echo`

Answer (score 0):

`header()` can take any URL, even relative ones. If you are testing something locally, something like `header("location: script/login_success.php")`

just remember that header() must be called before any content is output or it will do othing

Answer (score 0):

You can create a url for use in a header redirect by doing this.

```
$url = isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"])?"https://":"http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/script/login_success.php");
header("Location: $url");
```

This should resolve correctly on localhost or elsewhere.

Another option would be to set up a constant that represents your base url per environment

```
define("BASE_URL", "http://localhost/");
```

and use that to build the url

```
header ("Location: ".BASE_URL."script/login_success.php");
```